# page not redirecting properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am starting a website and everything was working fine until I made a few changes. I realized that after the changes I made to the view_profile page it wasnt redirecting properly back to the home page or any other page. It was just getting stuck here, and I undoed those changes but now its still not redirecting. Here is part of my code:

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once "php/connect.php" ;
include_once "php/timeFunctions.php" ;


if (isset($_GET['midfa']))
{
 $midfa = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['midfa']);     
}
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
{
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];

} 
else 
{
   header("Location: index.php");
   exit();
}


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE `memberID`='$midfa' LIMIT 1")
or die (mysql_error());


$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); 

if ($existCount == 0) 
{ 
 header("Location: index.php");
       exit();
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{ 
     //gather all member data here
}
```

in the same page I also have button links to the member profile, their pictures, etc. All the pages have the same button menu. The problem is that when I click any link in this particular page (view_profile.php) it doesnt redirect me! I played with the sessions and they are not getting lost or erased, so I dont know what the problem could be because these buttons work fine on any other page. Any help? 
P.S. if you want to check it out the website is avirix.com

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: Your problem might be in the files you include. Have you checked those for errors?

Comment: @vedarthk, actully there is and its best practice. it stops any further potential processing

Comment: @vedarthk Exiting after a redirect is good practice

Comment: I checked all the included files and they are fine. I know this because all my other pages include them as well and they are not giving me any of these problems

Comment: technically Location should be a absolute URI  but you usually get a way with relative one.

Comment: does your page stay at index.php or will it not go to index.php?

Comment: As an aside, did you know many people block Flash (myself included), and some mobile devices do not support it? So we get to the home page, and see...nothing but an image.

Comment: You should probably also put some check around your query execution and die if it fails

Comment: @magicianlam it goes to the member_profile page but it doesnt execute it

Comment: @Nikki9696 Im currently working on a css version of it but for the moment thats what i have

Comment: so that whole code is under member_profile. what is not executing. i believe you need to provide a bit more info for us to be of assistance.

Comment: well in the member_profile page I include two files which are connect.php and sessions.php. The connect.php connects to the database and the sessions.php does the same thing as this view_profile.php page, but instead of doing the $_GET['midfa']; it obtains the session id.

Comment: but that page works perfectly.

Comment: ok a little update... if I click the "View Profile" button in my member_profile (which will take me to the view_profile.php page) the midfa will be the same as the session_id, and if I click the home button while viewing my own profile, it redirects me properly, so maybe the sessions are getting mixed up

Comment: if that's the case. then echo all your sessions and comment all redirection at the moment to check what are your sessions holding.

Comment: @magicianIam ok I did what you said and all the sessions remain the same. But I got this error  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosoraweb016/b194/ipg.avirixcom/php/sessions.php:17) in /hermes/bosoraweb016/b194/ipg.avirixcom/php/sessions.php on line 150

Comment: @lomas09 those errors are from the headers. since there is this rule or sort that you must not echo anything before declaring a header. and that you must always have an exit for every header. what is the purpose of your sessions again?

Comment: ok i got rid of the header relocation. My sessions hold the information I use to gather the member's information from the database. So when they log in I store their id, password and email in sessions and i use those variables in the "sessions.php" file.

Comment: Why store all of those at a session, wouldn't id be enough as an identification. there could be a problem with your query, they might not be getting the appropriate values you expect them to get. also dont just use isset also do $var != null. since isset is not always that reliable. you could provide a bit more info in your question.

Comment: @magicianIam ok that did the trick. But now my question is, if I only use the session id in my query, wouldnt it be easier for lets say a hacker to modify it? Lets say their id is 100 and they modify their session id to 60, wouldnt they be able to see the profile of id 60?

Comment: @lomas09 they won't be able to set the session id, unless of course you set them using a get parameter. you should set those important variables using post to prevent hackers from modifying them.

Comment: so there is no way of modifying session ids?

Comment: no if you set it using post. if so then session would be a terrible variable.

Comment: ok thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

- check you don't have any space before the `<?php` opening tag
- check that your included files don't echo anything
- check that your `view_php` encoding is UTF8 NO-BOM

Comment: how do I check if the encoding is UFT8 NO-BOM